# I have to take the directory of a file in zip file

Tags: c#, zip, dotnetzip

Can someone helps me out with my problem.
I have to take a file's directory in zip file so i can calculate its MD5 hash (without unzip it). I am using `DotNetZip` Library but i can't find the solution of the problem. I'll show you what i've tryed and hope you will help as fast as possible.
Thanks!

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ofd.FileName))
    {
        foreach (ZipEntry f in zip)
        {
            GetMD5HashFromFile(ofd.FileName+"\\"+f.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with what you have?

Comment: Could you also show the `GetMD5HashFromFile` please?

Comment: public static string GetMD5HashFromFile(string filename)
        {
            using (var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                var buffer = md5.ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes(filename));
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(buffer[i].ToString("x2"));
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }

I've take it from this site.

The problem is it throws me an exception that the path isn't find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you do not extract the Zip entry, it is still in the archive. That is why it does not find the path.
I recommend to use the stream and calculate on that, without extracting.
**Be aware of that MD5 is no collision safe.**

You have to reference in your project the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll`.
Full working console application:

```
public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var z = ZipFile.OpenRead(@"C:\directory\anyfile.zip");
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry f in z.Entries)
        {
           var yourhash = GetMD5HashFromFile(f.Open());
        }

    }

    public static string GetMD5HashFromFile(Stream stream)
    {
        using (var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var buffer = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(buffer[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but i can't get it to work. If it is possible to help me little more?

Comment: What is the issue? exception? or what?

Comment: 1.Thre is no definition for "Open" so i replace it with OpenFile().
2.Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.Stream' to 'string' C:\Users\SerenitySoft\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ZIPFiles\Form1.cs 33 41 ZIPFiles

Comment: It throws me an error:
Error 1 'Ionic.Zip.ZipFile' does not contain a definition for 'OpenRead' C:\Users\SerenitySoft\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 20 29 ConsoleApplication1

Comment: I have tryed it but as i told you: It gives me an error for OpenRead, because ionic.Zip does not conteins a definition for it.

Comment: Sorry, I tought you use `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll`. If you can, use the .NET framework BCL.

Comment: C Sharper, thanks! I've used your code /with a little bit corrects. I put it in yours with correct/ . Now it works fine to me. Thanks again and i am gonna mark you code as the correct "Answer". Here is the used namespaces: <br/>
'using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Ionic.Zip;'

Comment: You don't use the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll`?

Comment: I looked at the project site of `Ionic.Zip` and it looks like that it is no more actively developed (since 2011) and still has bugs (Watch the review or issues). Therefore I wouldn't use this library and stick with the Microsoft libraries, if you can.