# how do we ensure that the extraction process is successful with C# ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory?

Tags: c#

I have this C# code which unzip a zip file.

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(_downloadPath, _extractPath);
```

To test download process, I use the file size and compare them. But for extraction process, how do we ensure that the extraction process is successful? It could be corrupted (extraction process stop half way). Can I use file count to compare?

Comment: Are you using any libraries?  it'd be helpful if you mention that.

Comment: @MihirDave, I didn't use any third party libraries. From what I see, `ZipFile` class is from `System.IO.Compression`

Comment: I saw the documentation for this method, I believe it'll throw a specific exception if something goes wrong. so wouldn't that be useful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you go ahead and compare md5 hash of files in archive and the ones that were extracted. Though it is definitely not the fastest process, this way you'll be 100% sure the data is not corrupted.

You can find how to get md5 of a file inside archive here:
[I have to take the directory of a file in zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005757/i-have-to-take-the-directory-of-a-file-in-zip-file)